# Is it possible to interface with MongoDB GridFS using DataGrip?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, datagrip

I've been using JetBrains Datagrip recently since I was able to get the whole suite for free. It's pretty nice, but I didn't notice any way to read GridFS using it. It seems like it should be common enough to have some sort of support, but I couldn't find any information online and its not immediately obvious from inside DataGrip.

Answer (score 2):

We have created a feature request to implement GridFS support:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-17458